# Dropdown menu being hidden with in table after table is toggle hidden/shown using jquery toggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a very wierd issue, here is the issue.

1. I have a table, and in the row of that table i have a dropdown list.
2. This table can be hidden, toggled show/hide by clicking on a button.
3. When the table is hidden and then unhidden the dropdown menu now is only rendered within the
   dimensions of the table. So if the dropdown menu is longer than the table it does not rendered that 
   portion of the dropdown.

   I am using the .toggle method from jQuery to hide/show the table and its something like this:

   ```
       $(".hideshow").click(function () {
           var tableToToggle = $(this).closest('table').next();
           $(tableToToggle).toggle("slow", function () {
               // Animation complete.
           });
       });
   ```

I have tried changing the z-index but this doesn't seem to have any effect, it just seems some how the drop down is stuck within the table now and will not render outside of it.

any help on solving this is welcome.

NOTE: working in ASP.net C#. using jquery.

Thank you.

Edit: more info:
Was hoping it was some flag I missed that someone could just say. Seems thats not the case :(

Also note that before I make the toggle on the table the drop down menu is working perfectly fine. renders as it should.

The drop down is inside of a div tag as so:

```
<Table>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <div>
       <button>  //Button toggles the list
       </button>
       <ul>
         <li/> //Dropdown
         <li/>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The tables are made at compile time, goes through a loop and creates all the tables and elements on the page.

there are some CSS class but nothing that stands out, just padding / text size alignment that sort of thing.

**SOLUTION:
Turns out it was jQuery. 
My jQuery Files were out of data, I had 1.8, updated to 1.11 and now everything works perfectly. So if you every come across something like what I describe up top, try update your jQuery files :)**

Comment: The simple answer is: get rid of the table! Use divs instead in a bootstrap grid layout or something. Tables can be useful in a few cases but they tend to have a few quirks. You can't use table rows and cells like normal divs.

Comment: The problem is not with jquery code, it is something else. See the working demo where dropdown is shown even if it is longer than table http://jsfiddle.net/ChaitanyaMunipalle/fzee0gwp/ . Please share some more information for better debugging.